# restify file upload - 500 error, socket is closed

Tags: node.js, restify

I am uploading file using restify api.

It gives me an error,

```
{
   "code": "InternalError",
    "message": "This socket is closed."
 }
```

The read api still works great but unable to upload the image. What could be the possible issue?

The code I was using,

```
exports.uploadfile = function (req, res, next) {
  var file_name = req.files.image.name;                
  var file_name_arr = file_name.split('.');
  var imageExtension = file_name_arr.pop();
  var imageName = Date.now()+"."+imageExtension;
  var newPath = process.cwd() + "/images/" + imageName;

  fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err){
      if(err) return next(err);
      res.json({
        image: imageName
      })
      return next();
    });                
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using a separate module to handle file uploads?

Comment: using fs - for uploading a file.

Comment: I just did a bare bones test using fs.rename to move the temporary file and it worked perfectly whether or not the node app was running in the background. Can you show how you are using fs to move the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging up a bit, here i found the answer. The above code reads the entire file into memory and then write it on the disk which is slow. Rather i have used streaming to write the file which works like a charm.

replacing fs.readfile in above code with

```
rr = fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath))

rr.on('error', function(err){
   console.log(error)
});

rr.on('finish', function(){
   //do ur work here
});
```

reference link: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Other way is to use fs.rename which is faster than the above specified method as it doesn't have to read the file at all.

```
fs.rename(req.files.image.path, new_file_path);
```

Comment: Even faster would be to use fs.rename. It wouldn't have to read in the file at all. The caveat would be that it probably won't work across file systems, so if you are writing to or from an NFS mount it might be problematic.